# Add two conditions in the array filter

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of a class that contains a description key and imageURL which are string, I want to filter this array to remove the index if they both are empty. I can do it for one of them:

```
let notes = data.filter({$0.description != "" })
```

but I need to do something like that, but it's not working of course

```
let notes = data.filter({$0.description != "" , $0.imageURL != "" })
```

could anyone help me on that? Thanks

Comment: You can use logical and, &&. `filter({$0.description != "" && $0.imageURL != "" })`. And you should also use `isEmpty` when checking for an empty string so `filter({!$0.description.isEmpty && !$0.imageURL.isEmpty})`

Comment: Prefer naming the variables inside the closure, like `{ aNote in ... }`, if you understand how it really works, then you would be able to use `$0` with proficiency (and $1, $0.1 etc if needed), and the logic behind it, since a comma didn't make sense at all for an "AND" logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the logical AND operator (`&&`). The `,` only works as an AND operator in `if` statements and should only be used when you use optional binding (`if let` or `guard let`).

```
let notes = data.filter { !$0.description.isEmpty && !$0.imageURL.isEmpty }
```

Unrelated to your question, but you can use the `isEmpty` property instead of comparing the `String` with the empty `String` literal, `""`.